# Does the block universe theory of time imply necessitarianism? What about conversely?

Tags: time, necessity

Is the block universe theory of time logically equivalent to necessitarianism? If not, does at least one imply the other? Or are they logically independent?

Comment: If it's in-principle-impossible to measure a difference between a claim being true and the claim being false, then it's not a claim about reality. As far as I can see, "is eternalism true" has the same status as "who would win in a fight between Batman and Edward Cullen?"